# Scroll to an element in android chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, appium

I have created a web application for mobile. I want to test it using appium. I am using python client of appium. In this I want appium to click on a link which may not be on the current screen. We may have to scroll down and click. The position of the link is dynamic and depends on the other content. So I want to scroll until that element is visible on the screen and click on the link. For achieving this I tried following

`driver.execute_script("mobile: scrollTo", {"element": element_to_click.id})`.

but that didn't work. Can somebody help me in achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen `scrollTo()` function don't work everywhere so what you can do use `longPress()` and `moveTo()` methods of TouchAction class to perform the scroll. Look [here](http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html)